# ed forms of Adjectives for intransitive verbs

Tags: adjectives

Why there are no adjectives(-ed form)for intransitive verbs, for example, words like happened (It was happened), occurred (It was occurred), etc, While transitive verbs having the adjectives ending with "ed"?

Comment: What in the world would an occurred thing be, or a happened thing, or a died thing, or a seemed thing,  or a become thing? Those make no sense. You can have a fell thing, but that does not mean what you may imagine it does.

Comment: 'Risen' is used in the sense 'having risen'. And 'departed' in the senses 'having departed' (usually into the next life).

Answer (score 3):

The constructions with adjectives that were originally participles of verbs are very closely related to the [**passive voice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) construction. And the passive voice construction, in turn, is only possible for transitive verbs.

As [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) says (p. 1436),

> There is a large-scale overlap between adjectives and the past participle forms of verbs, and since the verb *be* can take complements headed by either of these categories we find a significant resemblance, and often an ambiguity, between a verbal passive and a complex-intransitive clause containing an adjectival passive as predicative complement. Compare:
>
> [32]  i  *The kitchen window was **broken** by the thieves.*                    [verbal: *be*-passive]
>         ii  *They were very **worried**.*                                     [adjectival: complex intransitive]
>        iii  *They were **married**.*                                                                                   [ambiguous]
>
> *Broken* in [i] is a verb, *worried* in [ii] is an adjective, while *married* in [iii] can be either. The ambiguity of [iii] is very clear: in the verbal interpretation it is dynamic, describing an event, while in the adjectival interpretation it is static, describing the state resulting from some prior event. Compare *They were married last week in London* (verbal) and *Hardly anyone knew that they were married - that they had been for over ten years* (adjectival). We will see, however, that this sharp semantic distinction does not apply in all cases.
>
> Adjectival passives are passive only in a derivative sense, and we will not say that[32ii-iii] in their statal interpretations are passive clauses: they belong to the complex-intransitive construction. The term adjectival passive applies only to the predictive complement, that is, to the AdjPs [adjective phrases] *very worried* and *married*. Thus the clause *They were very worried* is not itself an adjectival passive - it merely contains one. Passives in the strict sense are always verbal;<sup>41</sup> more specifically, we restrict the term *be*-passive to clauses like [i] or [iii] in its dynamic interpretation, i.e. to clauses in which *be* is a catenative verb taking a bare verbal passive as complement.
>
> <sup><sup>41</sup>Adjectival passives are sometimes called 'pseudo-passives', though this term is more widely used for prepositional passives.</sup>

Having said this, many intransitive verbs allow [**prepositional passives**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Prepositional_passive), and in some cases it is possible to form adjectives that come from those. For example, from the prepositional passive

*This problem has been **talked about.***

we get the following adjective:

*This is a **talked-about** problem.*

Example of usage in published literature:

*corruption was **the world's most talked-about problem***
From Paul M. Heywood, *Routledge Handbook of Political Corruption* (2014) [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Routledge_Handbook_of_Political_Corrupti/LGzfBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22talked-about%20problem%22&pg=PT17&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22talked-about%20problem%22)

Comment: _He worked out 50 problems in the book. = The book has 50 worked-out problems_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, indeed. Also *a broken-into apartment*.